# Photosynthesis immature fruits

Tags: botany, photosynthesis

Do immature fruits perform photosynthesis? Yes they have chlorophyll bodies. But do they have stomata through which they can absorb carbondioxide like the green leaves? Sincerely Ulrik

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Both fruits and seeds often possess stomata as well as chloroplasts, which have been shown to be quite important in many cases for seed and fruit development.  It makes sense when you think about it.  If these vital components of the plant can make some of their own energy, rather than relying entirely on sugar reserves produced elsewhere (especially given how much sugar your average fruit has to produce), this would be a vastly more efficient system.  If you are interested in a more detailed look at fruit and seed stomata, the following paper should make for a good starting point:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2442508?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

The authors of this paper conducted an in depth investigation of the structure and functions of the fruit and seed stomata present in a number of species within the Eschscholzia genus.  It's an interesting read.

Comment: Yes. I grow grapes. Next year I shall seek out two clusters of grapes. One I shall leave exposed to sunlight, the other I shall cover with alu-foil. I shall let you know the result.